# GRPC services on Liberty (wlp-javaee8.21.0.0.8) failing to bind when deployed in EAR

Tags: grpc, war, websphere-liberty, ear

I have a project that contains an EJB application (jar) and a web application (war). The WAR contains grpc services. These GRPC services use the EJBs in the jar.

When I deploy the WAR alone everything works fine and I get the nice registration message from the grpc services

> [09/09/21 11:15:38:314 IST] 0000002c
> io.openliberty.grpc.internal.servlet.GrpcServerComponent     I
> CWWKT0201I: gRPC service provided by myproject is available at:
> /my.org.Referencedataservice/* [09/09/21 11:15:38:314 IST] 0000002c
> io.openliberty.grpc.internal.servlet.GrpcServerComponent     I
> CWWKT0201I: gRPC service provided by myproject is available at:
> /my.org.Advanceservice/*

But when I stick the WAR into an EAR to deploy together with the EJB archive I get an ffdc incident

> [09/09/21 11:18:28:653 IST] 0000002c
> com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I
> FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created:
> "com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: CWWKM0453E:
> WebSphere Application Server internal error occurred. Please contact
> WebSphere Application Server support with the following data:
> Container is not a module
> com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@763d3241
> (
> file:/C:/workspaces/disb-core/disb-ear/build/wlp/usr/servers/disbCoreServer/dropins/myproject.ear
> file:/C:/workspaces/disb-core/disb-ear/build/wlp/usr/servers/disbCoreServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/58/data/cacheAdapt/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_102/.overlay/
> ) io.openliberty.grpc.internal.servlet.GrpcServerComponent 251" at
> ffdc_21.09.09_11.18.28.0.log

Initially I was wondering is it just startup order. And it appears that initialize-in-order in application.xml is not being honored. It definitely tries to register the GRPC services before the EJB names become available, I can see that in messages.log.

But I can actually deploy the WAR standalone without a problem. Of course I get a runtime error if the EJBs arent present but the WAR starts up just fine.

So whats the difference between WAR standalone and WAR in an EAR in terms of GRPC services? Anyone come across this?

thanks

Carsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there's an issue open to track this bug here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/18492 along with a PR to resolve it.

I would recommend subscribing to the issue to track it's progress and inclusion into a future release.

Comment: Thank you, this issue was created on the back of a support case I opened.

Comment: For anyone interested this issue has been resolved and the fix is included into Liberty from version 21.0.0.11 onwards. gRPC WARs can now be contained in an EAR and will initialize and operate successfully. yay!